# Expression Builder using times

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, expression, time

I have brought in vector layer from a .csv file containing Total Response Time for Emergency Services Incidents.  While the times are in HH:MM:SS format I believe that having brought it in as a .csv turns all the fields in character format.  I'd like to use ruled-based symbology so I can color code response time bands. I've experimented with `to_time` and `make_time` but can't come up with an acceptable expression.

My first rule should be something like this:

`"TotalResponseTime"  <= 00:04:59` ..... so all features with TRT less than five minutes can be color coded.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `to_time` function, but you must indicate the format the string is in. For example:

```sql
to_time('00:04:59', 'HH:mm:ss')
```

The notation (`HH:mm:ss`) can be found in the help pane of the expression editor.

[image]

You can replace the time string in the expression for the field name containing the times.

##### Testing the response time

To test if it is less than 5 minutes, `make_time` can be used to create a time object with a value of 5 minutes:

[image]

The result in this case is `true` denoted by 1, `false` would be `0`.